# CreateQuantumTask operation: This account is not authorized to use this resource

Tags: amazon-braket

I have an AWS account with some credits on it. I enabled the following policies:

- AmazonBraketFullAccess,
  AmazonBraketJobsExecutionPolicy,
  AmazonS3FullAccess

but I am still getting the following error:

```
AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateQuantumTask operation: This account is not authorized to use this resource. In order to access additional resources, please contact customer support
```

when trying to run the following code example:

```
import boto3
from braket.aws import AwsDevice
from braket.circuits import Circuit

device = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:::device/quantum-simulator/amazon/sv1")

bell = Circuit().h(0).cnot(0, 1)
task = device.run(bell, shots=100)
print(task.result().measurement_counts)
```

from amazon-braket-sdk-python GitHub page:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python

I would appreciate any help regarding that. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I tried on a fresh notebook instance and was not able to reproduce. You might have an explicit deny on another role in their account, could you check?
[image]